# Parsing variables in curl with bash script

Tags: json, bash, curl, environment-variables, echo

Hey I am using conduit curl method to create tasks from post. It work fine when I run from terminal with hardcoded values. But when I try to execute it with variables it throws an error:

Script:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "$1"
echo "$2"
echo "$3"
echo "$4"
echo "$5"
echo '{
  "transactions": [
    {
      "type": "title",
      "value": "$1"
    },
    {
      "type": "description",
      "value": "$2"
    },
    {
      "type": "status",
      "value": "$3"
    },
    {
      "type": "priority",
      "value": "$4"
    },
    {
       "type": "owner",
       "value": "$5"
    }
  ]
}' | arc call-conduit --conduit-uri https://mydomain.phacility.com/ --conduit-token mytoken maniphest.edit
```

execution:

```
./test.sh "test003 ticket from api post" "for testing" "open" "high" "ahsan"
```

Output:

```
test003 ticket from api post
for testing
open
high
ahsan
{"error":"ERR-CONDUIT-CORE","errorMessage":"ERR-CONDUIT-CORE: Validation errors:\n  - User \"$5\" is not a valid user.\n  - Task priority \"$4\" is not a valid task priority. Use a priority keyword to choose a task priority: unbreak, very, high, kinda, triage, normal, low, wish.","response":null}
```

As you can see in error its reading $4 and $5 as values not variables. And I am failing to understand how to use $variables as input in these arguments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using single quotes around the last `echo` to so that you can use double-quotes inside the JSON, but that causes `echo` to print the string without expanding anything. You need to use double quotes for the string, so you'll have to escape the double quotes inside of it.

Replace the last `echo` with this:

```
echo "{
  \"transactions\": [
    {
      \"type\": \"title\",
      \"value\": \"$1\"
    },
    {
      \"type\": \"description\",
      \"value\": \"$2\"
    },
    {
      \"type\": \"status\",
      \"value\": \"$3\"
    },
    {
      \"type\": \"priority\",
      \"value\": \"$4\"
    },
    {
       \"type\": \"owner\",
       \"value\": \"$5\"
    }
  ]
}"
```

and it'll work. To avoid issues like this you can check http://wiki.bash-hackers.org and http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide for some general tips for `bash` newbies. Also, you can use [shellcheck](https://github.com/koalaman/shellcheck) with a lot of text editors, which will spot errors like this automatically.